# how to retrieve pivot data from another relationship in API resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models:
User, Suburb, City

> **City** *hasMany* **Suburb** and **Suburb** *belongsTo* a **City**.

> **User** *belongsToMany* **City** and **City** *belongsToMany* **User**.

> **Suburb** *belongsToMany* **User**.

There are two pivot tables between these models, and I am using the same API resource *User* for the response.

```
class User extends JsonResource
{
   public function toArray($request)
   {
        return 
        [
          'id' => $this->id,
           ........
        ];
   }

}
```

Now in **Suburb** page I want to retrieve a field *valid_from* from **City_User** pivot table data, So I tried

```
return [
 'valid_from' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('city_user', function(){
    return $this->pivot->valid_from;
   })
]
```

However, this returns null as $this->whenPivotLoaded seems point to **Suburb-User** pivot table not **City-User**. So this works fine if I navigate to the **City** page.

I also tried

```
return [  
 $this->mergeWhen($this->relationLoaded('city'), function () {
                return [
                    'valid_from' => $this->pivot->valid_from,
                ];
            }),]
```

City-User relation is loaded but still no luck.

**dd($this)**:

```
App\Http\Resources\User {#900
  +resource: App\User {#837
    #table: "user"
    #guarded: []
    #connection: "mysql"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
     .....
```

***User*** Model:

```
    public function city(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'city_user')
        ->withPivot('valid_from')
        ;
    }
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations package to eager load pivot relations. I'm not the author of the package